# Pulling Data from website using VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Im pretty new to VBA coding and searching on online and youtube hasnt yielded much help, as they all have their own way to do it and its been very confusing.

I can do this via "Data > Get External Data > From Web" but its pulls in way more then what I need. The data is also on a private network, you wont have access to it. Also, the Do while loop also generated an error, so I commented it out, as this site takes around 10-15sec to load up

I just need to pull the data from the Div Class and paste it into the sheet "Alps OB".

If I can get any help and or make this coding simple, would be much appreciated.

Edit*
Sorry about the missing code. Regarding about the data being pulled, Excel pulls the whole page, which comes out to around 1000 rows and 10 columns. where as, I if can manage to get this VBA code to work, I only need around 20 rows and 10 columns. IE loads the pages just fine without the "Do while" loop but gives me a runtime error and highlights "Loop Until objIE.readyState = 15"

```
Sub AlpsOB()
Dim HTML As HTMLDocument
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

objIE.Visible = True
objIE.navigate "https://alps.amazon.com/reports/show/tdp/outbound_joint/latest_BASE/YVR2"

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until objIE.readyState = 15

Set HTML = objIE.document
Dim elements As IHTMLElementCollection

Set elements = HTML.getElementsByClassName("tdp-content")
For I = 0 To elements.Length - 1
    Sheet2.Range("A" & (I + 2)) = elements(I).innerText
Next I


End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiCPF.jpg)

Comment: Please include your code, at least. Please be more clear in what you mean by "it pulls in way more then (sp) I need". Right now your question is not super clear, but if you were to EDIT it you may improve it enough that we could help.

Comment: That do loop is very important though. But as music2myear points out, please post the code so we can copy/paste it. Without it, it is much harder to help you, and I won't even try.

Comment: Also a learning curve, but powerQuery may be easier to filter/manipulate the data in question.